# Case insensitive option with Regex.compile/2

Tags: regex, elixir

I'm attempting to build a caseless regex binary using [`Regex.compile/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Regex.html#compile/2) but can't seem to find an example on how the option should be set.

```
Regex.compile("^(foo):?", :caseless)
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Regex.compile/3

The following arguments were given to Regex.compile/3:

    # 1
    "^(foo):?"

    # 2
    :caseless

    # 3
    "8.41 2017-07-05"

(elixir) lib/regex.ex:140: Regex.compile/3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### **In short**

According to the link you provided, [options](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Regex.html#compile/2) need to be provisioned as a `list` as you can provide multiple options. The following should work:

```
Regex.compile("^(foo):?", [:caseless])
```

---

## **In more detail**

The type specification is as follows:

```
compile(source, options \\ "") 
compile(binary(), binary() | [term()]) :: {:ok, t()} | {:error, any()}
```

The second line is the type specification in `dialyzer` and basically states that the `function` `compile` accepts two arguments:

1. The first one is a binary, corresponding to your `"^(foo):?"`
2. The second one is either a binary, or either a list containing several `terms`.

The return value will be either `{:ok, t()}` in the case of success, where [`t()` is a `%Regex{}` struct](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Regex.html#t:t/0) or either will be `{:error, any()}` in the case of an error.

Coming back to the discussion of the second parameter, in the case of a list, you will need to leverage the various options as mentioned [here](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Regex.html#t:t/0).

In the case of `binary`, you can provide the second argument as a one letter abbreviation. So whereas the following will fail:

- `Regex.compile("^(foo):?", "caseless")`

The following on the other hand succeeds:

- `Regex.compile("^(foo):?", "i")`

The mapping you can get from [the table of the various module modifiers I linked to above](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Regex.html#module-modifiers).

The main difference between the approaches stems from the fact that `Erlang` `Regex` as powered by `:re` builds on top of the `PCRE` standard. According to that standard, the various `module modifiers` are handled by the single lower case letters, such as `i`, `u` etc.. So you could combine accordingly both options with `binary` as follows:

- `Regex.compile("^(foo):?", "iu")`

which technically speaking should give you the equivalent of:

- `Regex.compile("^(foo):?", [:caseless, :unicode])`

This allows you to communicate about `Regex` in Erlang and in `Elixir` through either the language specifications, or either the `PCRE` specifications.

---

## **Highly Advanced Details**

As the `OP` rightly pointed out in the comments, there is some confusion as to why the `Regex` produced in two different ways(e.g. through `options` as `list` vs `options` as `binary`) looks differently.

To explain this discrepancy in more detail, consider the following scenarios:

- `r0 = Regex.compile!("(foo):?")` ---> `~r/(foo):?/`
- `r1 = Regex.compile!("(foo):?", "i")` ---> `~r/(foo):?/i`
- `--->`~r/(foo):?/`# ?????? WHERE IS THE`i` ?????

When confronted with this, one might gain the impression that the `Elixir` `Regex` is broken. `r0` and `r2` are identical and different from `r1`.

However, functionality wise, `r2` behaves like `r1`, not like `r0`, consider the following examples as shamelessly inspired by the comment of the OP:

- `Regex.replace(r0, "Foo: bar", "")`  ---> `"Foo: bar"`
- `Regex.replace(r1, "Foo: bar", "")`  ---> `" bar"`
- `Regex.replace(r2, "Foo: bar", "")`  ---> `" bar"`

So how is this possible?

If you recall from above, e.g. pertaining to the explanation of the type `t()`, a `Regex` in `Elixir` is nothing but a `struct` under the hood.

A `Regex` may be presented beautifully in the following way: `~r/(foo):?/`, but in reality it is nothing but something like this:
`%Regex{ opts: opts, re_pattern: re_pattern, re_version: re_version, source: source }`

Now, from all those `struct` fields, the only thing that counts at the end of the day is what is under: `re_pattern`. That will contain the fully compiled `Regex` with all the options. So we find that accordingly:

- `r1.re_pattern == r2.re_pattern`
  But
- `r0.re_pattern != r2.re_pattern`

As far as the `opts` field is concerned, that is a container solely reserved for the options in `binary` format. So you will find that:
 - `r0.opts == r2.opts == ""`
Whereas:
 - `r1.opts == "i"`

These same `opts` fields are utilized to beautifully display the options at the end of `Regex` accordingly, so you will see:

- `~r/(foo):?/` for both `r0` as well as `r2`
  But you will see:
- `~r/(foo):?/i` for both `r1`
  on account of the `opts` fields differing from each other.
  It is for this reason that you could manually update the `Regex` if you would like it to look more consistent by doing this for instance:
- `%{r2 | opts: "i"}` ---> `~r/(foo):?/i`

Except for the field, `re_pattern`, none of the other fields have any functional influence to the actual `Regex`. Those other fields are merely there for the purpose of documentation only.

Next, on the basis of the [source code](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/lib/regex.ex#L783), you can see that `binary` options get translated to the `list` version of options [because that is how `Erlang` regex engine, `:re` expects them to be.](http://erlang.org/doc/man/re.html#type-compile_option)

Even though not difficult in itself, the `Elixir` core team have opted not to provide translation for the reverse, e.g. from the actual list of `module modifier` atoms to the equivalent `PCRE` `binary` option, thus you end up with the `opts` field remaining empty and bereft of the corresponding options in `PCRE` `binary` format and thus, you end up with the defective rendering of the `Regex` as evidenced by the discrepancy above.

Above I have only delved into the mechanics that explain the discrepancy, however, whether such a discrepancy is warranted or not is another question in itself. I would be immensely grateful if someone with more insight than me could be so kind as to clarify if there is any way to defend such a discrepancy.

---

## **Conclusion**

- `r0 = Regex.compile!("(foo):?")` ---> `~r/(foo):?/`
- `r1 = Regex.compile!("(foo):?", "i")` ---> `~r/(foo):?/i`
- `r2 = Regex.compile!("(foo):?", [:caseless])` ---> `~r/(foo):?/`

`r1` and `r2` may look different, but they behave exactly the same.

Comment: I find it interesting the difference between these:
     `f1=Regex.compile!("(foo):?", "i")`
     ~r/(foo):?/i
     `f2=Regex.compile!("(foo):?", [:caseless])`
     ~r/(foo):?/
    `Regex.replace(f1, "Foo: bar", "")`
    " bar"
    `Regex.replace(f2, "Foo: bar", "")`
    " bar"